# Model Fit expects 1 array, but I got 768

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

I am new to TF and got a bit of a problem. I am trying to classify colored images with shape (150 x 150 x 3), into 30 classes.
While I am fitting the model I got the error:

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 768 arrays: ...

my code:

```
model = Sequential() 

model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(150,150,3)))

model.add(Dense(150, activation=tf.nn.relu)) 

model.add(Dense(150, activation=tf.nn.relu))

model.add(Dense(30, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam' ,loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy' ,metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=768)
```

the input arrays are not numpy arrays, when I try to cast them, numpy gives an error, that it could not broadcast (150, 150 , 3) into shape (150, 150)

furthermore the input array (x_train) is an array of np arrays with the dimension (150 x 150 x 3), so all in all x_train is in the shape of (768 x 150 x 150 x 3), as I have 768 observations (I hope at least)
y_train is just a simple array consisting of the labels.

As far is the input data goes, they are .jpg images that were imported in the following manner:

```
with Image.open(filename) as img:
images.append(np.array(img.resize((150,150))))

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, classes, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like x_train is a list containing 768 members, each of which is an np array of shape (150, 150, 3). However, x_train should be one np array of shape (768, 150, 150, 3) in order to feed it to the fit function. You can convert x_train into such as array:

```
x_train = np.array(x_train)
```

Comment: Exactly, before that i got an error that it could not be converted, as of now i realized that there are some observations with the shape of (150, 150 ,4), which caused this problem so I ommited them, but of course there is some other error now, I will try to solve them, it seems less complex, thanks for the help.